# Missing fields in graphql mutation payload

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relaymodern

I'm new in graphql. I need to perform a mutation using Relay Modern in a React app. According to docs mutation payload can be different from success response to error response. Everything goes fine with success response, but with error response I receive in console this warning:

**Warning: RelayResponseNormalizer: Payload did not contain a value for field `objectId: objectId`. Check that you are parsing with the same query that was used to fetch the payload.**

because error response does not contain objectId field. Apart from that script behave correctly. Here are some samples from docs.. A mutation example:

```
mutation{
    createObject(name: 'john') {
        objectId
        error
    }
}
```

a success response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "createObject": {
            "objectId": "123456",
            "error": null
        }
    }
}
```

and an error response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "createObject": {
            "error": "[Name should not be Empty]"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code in react component:

```
const mutation = graphql`
    mutation ComponentCreateObjectMutation($name: String) {
        createObject(name: $name) {
            objectId
            error
        }
    }
`;

commitMutation(
    environment,
    {
        mutation,
        variables,
        onCompleted: (response, errors) => {

            /* error is in response.error */
        },
        onError: (err) => {...}
    }
);
```

and this is the schema.graphql content:

```
type ObjectResponse {
    objectId: ID,
    error: String
}

type Mutation {
    createObject(name: String): ObjectResponse
}
```

What is the best approach to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to solve this one? Thanks.